# Design synchronous reversible counter with d flip flops

Tags: flipflop

I have to design a sync reversible counter with seq 0 1 3 5 6 10 0.I tried writing the numbers on 4 bits with current and next state but I get stuck at Kmaps. What I tried is in the pic below. Is it wrong to try solving it like this?[image]

Comment: is the `10` decimal or hexadecimal? (btw: you have it as a 9)

Comment: is this a school assignment?

Comment: its decimal and I have to correct that,you're right. It's not a school assignment I have counters for my digital electronics exam and I'm trying to understand this type of problems...but I just can't undrstand how to work with them

Comment: when you refer to 4 bits of data (a nybble), you use hexadecimal digits 0-9, A-F  (can be lower case) .... there is no 10 within 4 bit data  .... your counter runs 0,1,3,5,6,A,0

Comment: you actually need 5 bits ... `reversible counter`

Comment: And how will I work with 5 bits?

Comment: I was thinking right now maybe it's okay to write til 1010 and the next state for this one is 0000 and the rest of them till 1111 are represented by dont cares(same as the ones which are not in the sequence)

Comment: add Q4 as the direction term, but not D4, since the direction term is externally generated

Comment: I think I understand it now,I'll try implementing it

Comment: Hint:- Before you do that make your truth table 5 bits the extra bit is the up down control. Then map out the next D levels for each Q level combined with the up down level.